# How to get rid of .BACKUP files which are messing up my Git merge process?

Tags: git, github

I am merging a remote branch into my local branch and I want to overwrite all the Local class names starting with `A' with their corresponding remote branch files.

so I am using the command:

```
git checkout origin/master src/classes/A*
```

I hope the above command is correct[Please correct me if otherwise].
When doing so I am getting the below errors:

[image]

To fix the above errors, I tried the git rm command:

`git rm src/classes/AClassName.cls.BACKUP.4294.cls` but it throws the below errors:

[image]

How do I get rid of these .BACKUP files?

**NOTE**: These BACKUP files were created because I was trying to resolve merge conflicts using meld tool and in the middle of the process I closed meld tool without saving the changes. This is what atleast I could remember how these files were generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### git clean

You can do a git clean to remove all the un-tracked files (Backup files)

```
git clean -Xfd // capital X
git clean -xfd // small x
```

This will remove all the untracked / ignored files and more.

Read more about this clean command

#### Remove the files from your file system

```
rm -R **.BACKUP
```

Comment: The clean will remove other files as well. like ignored files, untracked files and more. mv will remove the pattern you choose to

Comment: rm to remove. mv is to move